# Passing Guid to IMultiValueConverter

Tags: c#, wpf, imultivalueconverter

I've created a multivalueconverter that I'm binding a telerik:RadMenuItem's visibility property.  This right-click menu is inside of an appointment that goes onto a Telerik calendar control.  I want to pass the ControlID (which is an attached property from the framework I'm using) into the IMultiValueConverter that I've made as a parameter.  So, I want to pass in the Guid (which comes in as the second value in an object array in the converter) and then cast it something to get the value so I can do my evaluations.  WPF isn't my strong suit and after trying a lot of things I can't seem to get the binding wired up.

```
<telerik:RadMenuItem Header="Cancel" x:Name="CancelMenuItem"
                                                   Click="RadMenuItemCancel_Click" 
                                                   myframework:BaseWindow.ControlID="e5c25731-e30e-472e-a5d7-ab190348a7cb">
                        <telerik:RadMenuItem.Visibility>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SecurityEnumToVisibilityConverter}">
                                <Binding Path="Appointment.AppointmentType" />
                                <Binding ElementName="CancelMenuItem" Path="myframework:BaseWindow.ControlID" />                
                            </MultiBinding>                     
                        </telerik:RadMenuItem.Visibility>
                    </telerik:RadMenuItem>
```

What am I missing here in that second Binding tag to pass in the contents of ControlID to my multivalue converter successfully?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try surrounding your path with brackets.

Path="(myframework:BaseWindow.ControlID)"

afaik this tells WPF that you are binding to an attached property